# It gives an error when I click to see my submissions on dspace

Tags: java, dspace, apache-cocoon

When I try to see my posts in dspace, I get the following error in xmlui/submissions path. I couldn't find any hint on how to fix the error

Invalid path: 'ıtem.metadata' [SELECT item FROM org.dspace.content.Item as item left join ıtem.metadata dc_date_accessioned WITH dc_date_accessioned.metadataField.id = :dc_date_accessioned WHERE item.inArchive = :in_archive AND item.submitter =:submitter ORDER BY STR(dc_date_accessioned.value) desc]

I get an error message when I click the link to see my submissions http://[domain.com]:8080/xmlui/submissions

Comment: This might be a bug in dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/content/dao/impl/ItemDAOImpl.java#findBySubmitter(Context, EPerson, boolean) fixed in commit 9b169a... (see https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/commit/9b169afd3544b31cec4298bb49d6459ac876519d.

Comment: The weird thing in your report is the appearance of "ıtem" instead of "item". Are you positive about this ?

Comment: This dotless lowercase "i" seems to be the standard counterpart for capital "I" in some Turkish locales, and a know issue with computer software. Please confirm lowercase dotless "i".

Comment: I will try the suggestions and share the results. I hope good results will come

Comment: What was the outcome, if any?

Answer (score 0):

### You most likely hit a localization-related bug in the codebase:

[line 131 of class `org.dspace.content.dao.impl.ItemDAOImpl`](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/c67185078478024b86cbfa58905bdc2b53d1878b/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/content/dao/impl/ItemDAOImpl.java#L131)  incorrecly expects the lowercase version of the string "Item" to be "item" (with a *dotted* "i"), as it is in many (most) scripts (typically "en"), but **which is not the case with some locales, like "tr" or "az", for instance**, where the lowercase counterpart is "**ıtem**" (note the leading *dotless* "i")

This should be fixed replacing 2nd argument of call to function addMetadataLeftJoin(),

```
Item.class.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() 
                           // localization-dependant, which is unwanted here
```

by

```
Item.class.getSimpleName().toLowerCase(new Locale("en"))  
                           // => "item", no matter the java system locale
```

(or even plainly by the expected outcome string `"item"` -- though this may raise code style or maintenance questions that go far behind your question/issue)